# Heroku login error in Nitrous.io

Tags: heroku, nitrousio

Today I tried to log into heroku from my Nitrous.io box. I forgot that I had two-factor authentication on my heroku account, so it did not let me login. Also not sure if I had put my key into heroku. It came up and said I needed to update heroku.

I followed the link https://github.com/heroku/heroku-two-factor. The thing is I did not have to do this with another box I made the other week.

More so though now the heroku command does not work at all. I get this error. I'm not even sure where to begin, this is the first issue I have it that I'm lost at. I don't want to mess things up. I have the entire app written, I just need to make it look nice, and would hate start over.

I have reinstalled heroku within the Nitrous autoparts, restarted my box and shut it down. No luck on any of the "Windows" fixes.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Ian

action@bedepraved-130452:~$ heroku login

/home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)

from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in`new' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in`'
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in`'
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in`'
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from /home/action/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.parts/bin/heroku:22:in`'
action@bedepraved-130452:~$

Comment: this should be working now, can you confirm? there was an incident with the latest version of the toolbelt

Comment: Re-installing fixed it. I worked with @Ian on this, and I ran the following commands on Nitrous to get a fresh install of the toolbelt: 1. `$ parts uninstall heroku_toolbelt` 2. `$ rm .heroku` 3. `$ parts install heroku_toolbelt`

Comment: @catsby same issue still.

Comment: @gman I tried your steps but I'm missing something on #2. rm: cannot remove `.heroku': Is a directory

Comment: Oops, use `rm -rf` for directories.